# How to get round-robin load blancer on Azure Container Services (AKS)

Tags: load-balancing, round-robin, azure-load-balancer, azure-aks

From everything I've read, my LoadBalancer service should be random. The sessionAffinity is None and I assume it's using the default iptables random algorithm. Despite this, I've noticed that the actual affinity is sticky to the client IP. Only after some time has past will a different pod be used for a specific client. This is very annoying as all my posts hit the same pod. Each post is for a long running operation that gets queued per-pod. Ideally each pod would have about the same number of operations queued, but only a single pod is getting posts using the default configuration.

I know about the kube-proxy parameters to change to ipvs, but I don't know where in the AKS cluster lifecycle I can set the kube-proxy parameters.

How do I switch the AKS cluster to use the IPVS round-robin load balancer algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the azure application gateway as a L7 round robin load balancer itself and connect it with your AKS. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsjUVhf2z38&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR1Slx8Y1cl4sEVY3aCSJb9MS7geKTdw7wwzMzGrVs5p2cvoLffdmU6D0Yw